# How to change the hosts file on android

Tags: android, hosts

I have successfully rooted my Samsung Galaxy Mini (android 2.2.1) and thought, that I could change anything (as root usually can).

I would like to change the hosts file on the android, to include some local addresses. However, I still get the message that I do not have permission to do that. I tried following options:

1. `adb push /path/to/my/new/hosts /system/etc` ... and  I got the response `Read-only file system`.
2. directly in the shell on the phone. But this didn't work either. I can do `su` in the console, but cannot change the file.

Isn't it strange, that as super user I am not allowed to change some files?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have root, but you still need to remount /system to be read/write

```
$ adb shell
$ su
$ mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Go here for more information: [Mount a filesystem read-write](http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html).

Comment: Can't adb do this directly? The usage shows: `adb remount                  - remounts the /system partition on the device read-write`

Comment: If you have root, you can find out the /system path and the fs type with: adb shell su -c cat /proc/mounts

Comment: @gsingh2011: `adb remount` gives me the error `remount failed: Operation not permitted` and `adb root` gives the error `adbd cannot run as root in production builds` on my unlocked Nexus 4. If you know how to get adb remount to work, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @ClaytonHughes I know this is old, but for future thread-goers, `adb root && adb remount` works for me just fine on CM10.2 on the Nexus 7 (2013).

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy Core with Android 4.1.2 'su: not found'. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @naXa. But to make it read-only again, use `mount -o ro,remount /system`.

Comment: @TylerCollier Of course... silly copy-paste error in a comment.) 
When done, do not forget to remount partition read-only again, for safety reasons. The correct command is `mount -o ro,remount /system`

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, even with remount and root.

Comment: Not work for me, is there any further fix?

Comment: @Tyler thanks for the reminder. A perfect answer might include this information.

Answer (score 45):

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

This assumes your /system is yaffs2 and that it's at /dev/block/mtdblock3  the easier/better way to do this on most Android phones is:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Done.  This just says remount /system read-write, you don't have to specify filesystem or mount location.

Comment: On my device (Milestone 3 with 2.6.35.7-g9f70789) "device" is a required parameter for mount. I was able to leave out -t yaffs2 though.

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /system` worked for me; the other command, `mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system` resulted in: `mount: Permission denied`.

Comment: Note that I need to do `mount -o rw,remount /system` in Nexus 5X (`remount,rw` will get "Device or resource busy" error.)

Comment: This works well.

Answer (score 14):

That didn't really work in my case - i.e. in order to overwrite hosts file you have to follow it's directions, ie:

```
./emulator -avd myEmulatorName -partition-size 280
```

and then in other term window (pushing new hosts file /tmp/hosts):

```
./adb remount
./adb push /tmp/hosts /system/etc
```

Comment: That's true, but that counts only for the emulator. I was working with a rooted phone (Samsung Galaxy Mini, although I think it does not really matter what phone it is). And on a physical device you have to remount the system partition.

Comment: you right, i tested it only on emulator. good to know, thanks.

Comment: Does't work with latest sdk (4.0.x) ./adb push /etc/hosts /system/etc
failed to copy '/etc/hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': Out of memory

Comment: Mariuz - thx, good to know. i did it on 2.3.

Comment: @Mariuz, what -partition-size value did you use? It worked for me on the 4.0.4 emulator if I use a value greater than 215 (which I believe is the size of system.img for the AVD).

Comment: It works for me fine! API level 15

Comment: This is an older thread but it's worth nothing that if you don't specify "-no-snapstorage" when starting the emulator you might start the snapshot which won't have the partition size. I had the same issue until I added "-no-snapstorage"

Answer (score 11):

Probably the easiest way would be use this app [Hosts Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treb.hosts&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50cmViLmhvc3RzIl0.) . You need to have root

Comment: Sure,  but the description of the question starts with "I have successfully rooted my Samsung Galaxy Mini",  so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: From what I can tell, this app just lets you edit entries one at a time.  I'd like to read in a 10MB new host file.