# How to write to a system file - Android

Tags: android, file, root, overwrite

I working on a root - base programm, but I'm a little bit confused on how to use `DataOutputStream`to **edit** and **save** a system file located at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` (File name is `scaling_max_freq`)

Can anyone help me out? Can this happen without having root access?

*(Let's suppose that root access is granted by a process named `p`)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write files to /system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268717/write-files-to-system)

Comment: No..I just want to edit the file and then just save it again where it was. Thanks for your answer!