# Moving Apk to SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Moving to SD Card actually copies the apk in /data/app folder to  SD card.
I wanted to do the same from my code.

I tried this but it failed as `canWrite()`, `setWriteable(true)` and `delete()` returns false

```
File apkFile = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
apkfile.delete();
```

Is it at all possible to delete/move the apk to sd Card (and not copy it)?

FYI: `installLocation` would not help me. So, I had to take the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can not move /delete installed apk file without ROOT privileges .

If you want to move/delete installed apk than you need  a ROOTED android device.
becase installed apk is inside **system/** directory and it  is mounted as read-only. I had to remount it with this

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Read more about [how to write files to system/ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11268717/6711591)

Comment: Does this apply for the same apk i.e if sample.apk was installed and the code inside sample.apk wants to remove the sample apk after installation, isn't that possible?