# HttpHostConnectException: Connection refused Android

Tags: android, json, https, http-post

I am trying to connect via HttpPost and send a username and password to a website and then receive a string from that website. I have tried various methods that have worked for me in the past but now when I send the username and password identifiers the app times out for as long as 4 minutes and then spits out the following exception:

```
 07-16 16:32:32.897: W/System.err(632): Unable to connect to the server
    07-16 16:32:32.907: W/System.err(632): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://devdashboard.company refused
    07-16 16:32:32.917: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    07-16 16:32:32.917: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    07-16 16:32:32.917: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    07-16 16:32:32.917: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    07-16 16:32:32.917: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    07-16 16:32:32.917: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    07-16 16:32:32.927: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    07-16 16:32:32.927: W/System.err(632):  at company.android.dashboard.app.HttpHelperAndroid.sendToHttp(HttpHelperAndroid.java:66)
    07-16 16:32:32.927: W/System.err(632):  at company.android.dashboard.app.DashboardAppActivity.goToDashboard(DashboardAppActivity.java:62)
    07-16 16:32:32.927: W/System.err(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-16 16:32:32.937: W/System.err(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-16 16:32:32.937: W/System.err(632):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
    07-16 16:32:32.947: W/System.err(632):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    07-16 16:32:32.947: W/System.err(632):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
    07-16 16:32:32.947: W/System.err(632):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    07-16 16:32:32.957: W/System.err(632):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-16 16:32:32.957: W/System.err(632):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-16 16:32:32.967: W/System.err(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    07-16 16:32:32.977: W/System.err(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-16 16:32:32.977: W/System.err(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-16 16:32:32.977: W/System.err(632):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    07-16 16:32:32.987: W/System.err(632):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    07-16 16:32:32.987: W/System.err(632):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-16 16:32:32.987: W/System.err(632): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /50.19.240.232 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    07-16 16:32:32.997: W/System.err(632):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    07-16 16:32:32.997: W/System.err(632):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    07-16 16:32:32.997: W/System.err(632):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    07-16 16:32:33.007: W/System.err(632):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    07-16 16:32:33.007: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    07-16 16:32:33.017: W/System.err(632):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    07-16 16:32:33.017: W/System.err(632):  ... 22 more
    07-16 16:32:33.027: W/System.err(632): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    07-16 16:32:33.047: W/System.err(632):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    07-16 16:32:33.047: W/System.err(632):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    07-16 16:32:33.047: W/System.err(632):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    07-16 16:32:33.057: W/System.err(632):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    07-1
    6 16:32:33.057: W/System.err(632):  ... 27 more
```

Internet permission IS enabled in my XML manifest file

My current implementation goes like this:

```
  String LOGIN = "email@gmail.com";
        String PASSWORD ="password1";

        //JSONObject to send the username and pw
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        //put the path in the JSONArray object

        JSONArray vect = new JSONArray();
        vect.put("company Android Library");
        vect.put("Rocket Ship");

        int duration = 50;
        try {
            json.put("email", LOGIN);
            json.put("password", PASSWORD);
            json.put("json", "true");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "ABOUT TO SEND:" + json.toString());

        JSONObject inJson = HttpHelperAndroid.sendToHttp(json, "http://devdashboard.company/login");

        if(inJson != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "RECIEVED the JSON:" + inJson.toString());
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "THE RESPONSE WAS NULL");
    }
```

And the HttpHelperAndroid class looks like so:

```
     public class HttpHelperAndroid
    {
        private static final String TAG = "HttpHelperAndroid";//TAG for the LogCat(debugging)


    private static boolean responseSuccessful = true;

    /**
     * sends the JSONObject parameter to the desired URL parameter and gets the response
     * 
     * @param url the URL to which the JSONObject should be sent
     * @param jsonObjOut the JSONObject that is to be sent
     * @return the response from the server as a JSONObject
     */
    public static JSONObject sendToHttp(JSONObject jsonObjOut, String url) {
        responseSuccessful = true;
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(url);

            //convert the JSONObject to a string
            StringEntity se;

            //set our StringEntity to the JSONObject as a string
            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjOut.toString());

            // Set HTTP params
            httpRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); //for gzip compression

            //get the current time
            long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                //execute the http request and get the response
                response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
            }
            catch(HttpHostConnectException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
                e.printStackTrace();
                responseSuccessful = false;
            }

            //only continue executing if we got a response from the server
            if(responseSuccessful)
            {
                //print how long the response took to the LogCat if it's on

                    Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-oldTime) + "ms]");


                // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    // Read the content stream
                    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                    Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                        in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                    }

                    // convert content stream to a String
                    String resultString= streamToString(in);

                    //close the stream
                    in.close();

                    // convert the String into a JSONObject
                    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

                    //take a peak at the JSONObject we got back if the LogCat is on

                        Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

                    //return the JSONObject we got back from the server
                    return jsonObjRecv;
                } 
            }
        }
        //catch any exception that was thrown
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Print the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String streamToString(InputStream is)
    {
        //create a new BufferedReader for the input stream
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        //create a new StringBuilder to append the lines
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //initialize an empty string
        String line = null;

        try
        {
            //iterate as long as there is still lines to be read
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                //append the line and a newline character to our StringBuilder
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        //catch an IOException and print it
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //close the stream when we're done
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                is.close();
            } 
            //catch and print an exception if it's thrown
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //return the stream converted to a string
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And here is my XML just for kicks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="company.android.dashboard.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/company_android_ico"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have used the HttpHelper class in past projects and it has worked for me, in addition I tried to implement this using nameValuePairs:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email@gmail.com"));  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", "true"));  
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

And this yielded the same result.

Could this somehow be a certificate thing? or perhaps something to do with a corrupt XML file( I tried remaking the project and the xml file) [Android HTTP Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9469060/1437824)
Or maybe some sort of Android hosts file issue?

I'm open to any suggestions!

I have examined this from a lot of angles and I'm happy to provide any other information that would be helpful! I really appreciate your time!

**NOTE:** The url is a dummy url, and not the actual one I am connecting to, for security reasons. I am able to curl the actual website from the command line with the parameters and it works and I am also able to login normally from the web browser.

**EDIT** I have identified the problem! But not the solution unfortunately. So the issue is that I am using a dev server url that doesn't have a domain entry on the global DNS server. So to fix this I somehow need to edit the hosts file on my Android device/in the emulator...does anyone know how this can be done legitimately?

Comment: According to the second line in your logcat:

>07-16 16:32:32.907: W/System.err(632): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://devdashboard.company refused.

Are you sure this isn't just an network issue rather than a problem with your code?

Have you checked the server configuration?

Comment: Also are you sure it should be a post?

Comment: also please limit what you post. You should edit out information that is specific to your environment.

Comment: ping the url and ip address of your connection to get more information.

Comment: @TJ Thind I am able to access the website via a browser and by curling from the command line so I think that it isn't a network issue, but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @VinC Did you do that from the device or emulator? Other than that, I'm out of ideas for now.

Comment: @TJThind I tried both a Nexus S 4g and an emulator and I still get the hanging behavior, thanks for trying! Let me know if anything else comes to you

Comment: @VinC I'm having the same error, but rarely it happens to me only on tablets on cellphones is working right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have identified the problem! So the issue is that I am using a dev server url that doesn't have a domain entry on the global DNS server.

So there are two possible solutions to this issue:

1) Editing the hosts file on the Android device (requires rooting your phone): [How to change the hosts file on android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7794659/1437824)

2) Getting the server registered on the global DNS server.
(also hard to do if you're not responsible for the url)

Anyways I hope this helps someone else too!

Answer (score 3):

Please follow these solution may be among these one solve your issue.

1> check your manifest file internet permission there or not.

2> check your url with browser by rest client and pass the appropriate request.

3> open the url in mobile like:- **http://your ip address/port** that's it just for checking do you have a permission or not to open this url in mobile.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities

1) the url is incorrect  "http://devdashboard.company/login" is not right.  At least check in browser. 
   ping the host as well.

2) This should be an https connection instead.

3) there is some certification required.

4) You are missing a port number.  or domain has not been setup correctly.
     perhaps port 80 the default is incorrect?

5) the call should not be a post.

In general you are either responsible for the server or you are not.  It appears that it is some elses responsibility, and you should ask them what the correct url and parameters are.  So its probably no ones fault, but you need to ask them about the connection to verify.

The other thing you can do is to try and see what the url looks like in an application that is succesfully connectiing. take a look that this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So the url is a dummy url I used to protect the server I'll edit my question to reflect that. So what should it be if not a post?

Comment: So I'm able to curl from the command line with the parameters above so I think it is a post, and that is another reason it makes me think it is some issue with my code. Additionally it definitely should be https, but I have tried it with both during my efforts to figure out the issue. Do you know if the certification could be causing this/how I could check?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in wifi sleeping.
Please use

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL , "MyWifiLock");
wifiLock.acquire();
```

and permission:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK";
```

Answer (score 1):

This post is old, but it is the first result when googling this error. I encountered the same exception, and everything was completely correct in my code. I commented out the line containing the INTERNET permission in my AndroidManifest.xml, ran the app, clicked/tapped my button to send the HTTP request and get the exception, closed the app, went back to the manifest, uncommented the permission line, ran the app again, and the exception was resolved!

This kind of bugs in 2015 (and in "advanced" tools like the latest compile tools for Android API 21, and Intellij IDEA 14) drives me mad! You are approaching your deadline, and this sort of bugs completely disrupts your work!