# Android connect to WebService in local network

Tags: android, web-services, networking, connection

I had a WebService running from my local machine which would work fine if it was accessed by the emulator.

Due to some enterprise BS, I needed to move the server that runs the WebService to another machine (a VM).

This caused my Android application to stop working.

I can access the WebService in the VM using my browser, I get the JSON response perfectly, but I can't using the emulator - I get the "Connection Refused" error.

What do I need to change? Or what do I need to ask the IT department to change regarding either my local machine or the remote VM?

thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look a this.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514038/httphostconnectexception-connection-refused-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514038/httphostconnectexception-connection-refused-android

Comment: fixed it, I think. needed to start the emulator without network connections on my machine, launch the emulator and start the network connection again. details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15502466/1756496). Thanks for the help, nonetheless, that still helped me!