# rooted android read only file system error

Tags: android, root, roottools

I'm trying to modify `/etc/hosts/` file and for that I make a separate file in external storage and then `cp` it to the location. I'm getting these error messages:

```
01-14 18:51:51.069: E/HostsActivity(5356): rm failed for /etc/hosts, Read-only file system
01-14 18:51:51.079: E/HostsActivity(5356): failed on '/mnt/sdcard/hosts' - Cross-device link
```

What do I do?

I'm using [RootTools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/Usage).

My code:

```
        try {
            String fn = write_file("hosts", hostsData);
            RootTools.getShell(true).add(new Command(0, "rm /etc/hosts",  "mv " + fn + " /etc/hosts")
            {
                @Override
                public void output(int arg0, String arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("HostsActivity", arg1);
                }
            }).waitForFinish();
            tv_status.setText("Done");

        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            Log.e("HostsActivity", ioe.toString());
            tv_status.setText(ioe.toString());
        }
```

I have asked for root permissions in the beginning of the activity in the `onCreate`

```
if (!RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Root access not given. Please ensure root access.");
            setContentView(tv);
        }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hosts);
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remount /etc by default it is Read-only file system.

Than you need to check permissions on the /etc/hosts and maybe you need to correct file permissions using chmod command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794659/how-to-change-the-hosts-file-on-android

Comment: tried this but still there's an error: `RootTools.getShell(true).add(new Command(0, "mount -o rw, remount /system",  "cp " + fn + " /etc/hosts")`