# How to access Laravel Homestead on other devices?

Tags: php, laravel, networking, remote-access, homestead

My machine and Android devices are on the same network.

- Machine IP: `192.168.0.11`
- The IP where Homestead is running: `192.168.10.10`

If I enter `192.168.0.11:8000` on my Android device I can use only one site.

How can I enter all sites stored in Homestead?

This is my `Homestead.yaml` file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Homestead-Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Homestead-Projects

sites:
    - map: site1.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Homestead-Projects/Site1/public
    - map: site2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Homestead-Projects/Site2/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - db_site1
    - db_site2

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

This is my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   host

#Virtual Hosts on Homestead
192.168.10.10   site1.com
192.168.10.10   site2.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

You have to add a row for each site in your host file on the remote machine (just like in the server where Homestead is running) but with the server's IP adress. Then just type `sitename.local:8000`.

### Example

In your case the server's IP is `192.168.0.11`. Within this server, Homestead serves requests on `192.168.10.10`. So in the host file of the server you have these lines:

```
192.168.10.10   site1.com
192.168.10.10   site2.com
```

You have to copy these rows to the remote PC's host file and then replace the IP address with the server's IP: `192.168.0.11`.

```
192.168.0.11   site1.com
192.168.0.11   site2.com
```

Depending on your OS you may have to restart the PC or the DNS service. After that, you can access the sites from the remote PC in these addresses:

```
site1.com:8000
site2.com:8000
```

### Note

Keep in mind that editing (writing) the hosts file requires superuser/administrator permissions. This is easy to solve in a PC, if you have access to the administrator account, but can be complicated on a mobile device. For Android check out these questions:

- [Android Enthusiasts: How to edit 'etc/hosts' file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/60150)
- [Stack Overflow: How to change the hosts file on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7794659/1494454)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://xip.io/ to setup a magic domain name and you can use these domains to access virtual hosts on your development web server from devices on your local network.

Installation is also easy too https://github.com/basecamp/xip-pdns

If you are using vagrant you can also use vagrant share.

Comment: What is the right way to do with homestead and xip, if the IP for homestead sites is 192.168.10.10?

Comment: Honestly I never tried it personally but I see an accepted answer here that you can try https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-multiple-sites-from-same-network

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the right answer [acess homestead from external](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/any-comprehensive-guide-to-make-a-homestead-vm-available-through-the-local-network)

all you need to just add default server on your nginx.conf

```
listen 80 default_server;
```