# Laravel app running on Homestead - how to access it on a mobile device?

Tags: windows, laravel, laravel-5.4, homestead

I'm running an app on Laravel Homestead. My OS is Windows 7. The **hosts** file:

```
192.168.10.10 myapp.dev
```

My PC uses the LAN Internet connection.

Now, I would like to be able to access **myapp.dev** on a mobile device.

I have tried **[this (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675025/access-to-laravel-5-app-locally-from-an-external-device)**, as well as **[that (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976448/how-to-access-laravel-homestead-on-other-devices/43144708#43144708)**. None of these worked for me. If I use the `php artisan serve` approach (link **1**), my IPv4 gets rewritten to myapp.dev, and the site cannot be found.

How do I access my Homestead-based app on a phone?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857012/470749 helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Homestead 5.x**

As of Homestead 5.x, ngrok software is included in your homestead environment. You can use the `share myapp.dev` command to fire off ngrok to listen for `myapp.dev`. Please refer to the [Laravel Homestead documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) (Sharing Your Environment)

**Homestead versions without ngrok included**

You can change your nginx configuration file to listen on all requests and use your local IP `http://yourip:8000` instead of `myapp.dev`, but the easiest way to archive this is by creating a secure tunnel to your machine with software like [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com/)

With your local domain `myapp.dev` you can basically run the following command after you served your webserver:

`ngrok http 192.168.10.10:80 -host-header=myapp.dev`

ngrok will generate a secure url which is available on your local network, but also publicly so you can share it with your friends/colleagues.

[source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/any-comprehensive-guide-to-make-a-homestead-vm-available-through-the-local-network)

Comment: And do I install and use ngrok on my Windows machine, or do I do this within the VM (when I'm ssh-ed to my environment with `vagrant ssh`)?

Comment: You can do both, but as of Homestead 5.x and up ngrok is included in your homestead environment. Please refer to the changes in my answer.

Comment: That's a nice solution, but it is a bit flawed. E.g. if you use the `action()` helper to build URL-s, it will, of course, take you out of the ngrok.io domain (as it uses the `APP_URL` environment setting). This means you cannot move across the site freely. Overwriting the `APP_URL` after ngrok has started breaks the service.