# android: mapping hostname to ip

Tags: android, ip, hosts, server-name

There is a file called hosts on windows/linux to map server name to ip address. Is there a way for android?

```
 192.168.1.22  domain1.com     
 192.168.1.22  domain2.com
```

The reason for this is to test web app running on windows machine using HTTPS.

Comment: Android based on Linux, so the answer is YES, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794659/how-to-change-the-hosts-file-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Similar question, different StackExchange site:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file

In general, [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) is your friend.  You will also need to turn on Developer Mode, but I expect that you're already doing that as part of development.

/etc/hosts is still /etc/hosts, since Android is Linux at its heart.